# error access violation at address 6172676F in delphi 2006

Tags: delphi, delphi-2006

I am working with external DLL file in Delphi 2006 when I used on of the function to get serial number from my reader the function work good but after that i got an error "access violation at address 6172676F"
the code :

```
const NLS_DOF = 'NLS_DOF.dll';
function dof_open(lpszPortType: LPCWSTR; lpszParam: LPCWSTR; lpszDevType: LPCWSTR): THandle; stdcall;external NLS_DOF;
function dof_close(hPort: THandle): Integer; stdcall; external NLS_DOF;
function dof_query(hPort: THandle; lpszQueryBuf: LPCWSTR; lpszResBuf: LPWSTR; dwResBufSize: DWORD): Integer; stdcall;external NLS_DOF;

procedure TForm1.Button3Click(Sender: TObject);
var str:pwidechar;
begin

hPort:= dof_open('com','com=1;baud=9600','2D');
dof_query(hport,'SN',str,1000);

ShowMessage(str);
end;
```

when I reach to the line of showmessage(str) i got the error 
and I tried to delete the line i got the same error at the end;
please any help or if there is an error in my code.

Comment: Maybe you are supposed to pre-allocate Str before the call to dof_query. Try, say, Str := AllocMem(4096) before that call.

Comment: Can I asked for another thing or I must ask in new quetion

Comment: Have a look at the help center. And also keep in mind this is a Question-Answer-Board and how can you accept one (right) answer if you ask more than one question?

Comment: @500 Please, make an answer of your correct comment. We'll have one less unanswered question.